# Converting Parasolid CAD files into cubic voxels to model for residual stresses on Abaqus CAE

Tags: python, abaqus, cad, voxel

I am simulating the laser power bed fusion process. Using Abaqus CAE and user subroutines. I have successfully managed to update my stresses onto a simple block structure and visualize the residual stresses and distortion due to the thermal strains during the fabrication process. [CAE mesh (brick elements)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnWhO.png) The part should consist of a perfect cubic mesh in order to conduct the layer activation.

When it comes to complex geometries it becomes complicated to achieve a perfect equally sized mesh [mesh with imperfections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qvUM.png). I would like to know how i can convert my part geometry into equally sized voxels. To perform the stress updating onto each elements. And the possibilities of converting a generated voxel file into an '.inp','.iges' or other 3D part/mesh file so that it can be uploaded onto Abaqus CAE. Thank you very much in advance.